# Class destory issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have three classes.  Main class that creates the container for the mainframe frame, mainframe class which is nothing but a frame with an enable/disable button and a kill button and an application exit button. The third is a class that has a loop.

The "main" creates the mainframe and the instance of the loop class. The loop class has a variable stating if it is running or not and has two functions, one that pauses and un-pauses the loop enable (pause is by spacebar) and the other to stop(stop is by escape). You can tell more by the code.  If problem is I don't just want to stop the class, I want to delete the class all together. How do I do this based off my code?
`
    from mycomm import commloop

```
class main(tk.Tk):
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frames = {}
        for F in (mainframe, otherframe):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame("mainframe")
    self.b = commloop(self)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def deletecommloop(self):
        del self.b

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

class mainframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.amiset = False
        #''''code to frame stuff
        buttont1 = tk.Button(frame5, text="create comm loop",
                         command=self.setme)
        buttont1.place(relx=0.444, rely=0.496, height=42, width=90)

        buttontt1 = tk.Button(frame5, text="kill comm loop",
                         command=self.killcommloop)
        buttontt1.place(relx=0.244, rely=0.496, height=42, width=90)

    def setme(self):
        self.amiset = not (self.amiset)

    def killcommloop(self):
        self.controller.deletecommloop()



class commloop():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.running = False
        self.aboutToQuit = False
        self.root = root
        self.someVar = 0
        self.root.bind("<space>", self.switch)
        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.stop) 
        self.page= root.get_page("mainframe")

        while not self.aboutToQuit:
            try:
                self.root.update() # always process new events

                if self.running:
                    # do stuff
                    self.someVar += 1
                    print(self.someVar)
                    time.sleep(.1)

                else: # If paused, don't do anything
                    time.sleep(.1)
            except:
                self.aboutToQuit=True #does this need to be here?

    def switch(self, event):
        if (self.page.amiset):
            print(['Unpausing','Pausing'][self.running])
            self.running = not (self.running)

    def stop(self, event):
        self.aboutToQuit = True
```

`

the loop code I found on the internet.  The aboutToQuit only keeps it from looping. I want the kill button on the mainframe page to call the killcommloop in main (since that is what started the commloop), but I am getting the error:

```
    File "C:/testloop/mainframe.py", line 101, in killcommloop
    self.controller.deletecommloop()
    File "C:/testloop/main.py", line 66, in deletecommloop
    del self.b
    AttributeError: b
```

Comment: Nobody can help?

Comment: I think you should take a look at object oriented programming in general, because this is very confused

Comment: if there is a better way of doing it, I am fine to change it. This is just something I found on this stackoverflow.  I basically need a loop to go through a treeview and do something with the values on each row in the treeview, and a way to start/pause/stop the loop. I'm open for any suggestions as into the proper and best way to do this.

Comment: If I was you, I would try to write your own code and if you have problems, post here on SO

Comment: I know how to do for each item in the treeview loops, but not sure on how to interrupt the loop using a keypad