# str' object has no attribute 'get' python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding for use on a raspberry pi.
I have something like the following dictionary,

```
self.appData = {"v": tk.StringVar(), "k": tk.StringVar()}
```

Then I set a default value

```
self.appData["v"].set("G")
```

Then I have everything setup for keypad input.

In my function that deciphers the key that was pushed, I take the keypad push and it suppose to take the string from the current v (self.appData["v"].get()) and then add the new keypad push to it.

Ex: 1st keypad push is "a", The function that deciphers the keypad button pushed, I have something like the following:

```
x = self.appData["v"].get() + key
self.appData["v"].set(str(x))
```

so it should get "G" from the dictionary and the "A" to it.  Then I set v to the new x. It works fine the first time, then the second time it goes through that function I get the error:

str' object has no attribute 'get' python

Comment: Hi, should `self.appData = {"v": tk.StringVar(), "k", tk.StringVar()} ` be `self.appData = {"v": tk.StringVar(), "k": tk.StringVar()} `?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley made a correct comment, I was giving some things for granted, but there is no info in the question supporting that. I deleted my answer

Comment: No, your answer was absolutely correct.

Comment: @mScientist I  know, but I wanted to rewrite it better,  explaining the things I had taken for granted. An answer is not useful if it only solves your problem, but it's not general enough for others to be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are setting self.appData["w"] as a string:

```
self.appData["v"].set("G")
```

This only works because tk.StringVar has a set method. This is not how you assign a value inside a dict. In the same way, this line is wrong:

```
x = self.appData["v"].get() + key
```

so you are calling the get() method on a string, and strings don't have a get method.
I guess that what you want to do is:

```
x = self.appData.get("v") + key
self.appData["v"] = x
```

Comment: I am doing self.appData.get("v") where I use (x=self.appData["v"].get() + key), I just need to set it to another variable, add the second string to it and reset v to the new variable.

Comment: What do you mean? x=self.appData["v"].get() + key at that point of the code is equivalent to x='G'.get() + key . That's the cause of the error

Comment: In my answer, I give for granted that key is a string

Comment: You claim that the OP is setting `self.appData["w"]` to a string. Why do you say that? There's nowhere in the code where that happens.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to explain everything better

Comment: yes, key is also a string.  So what is the difference between self.appData["v"].get() and self.appData.get("v")?

Comment: @micric, behind the scene there is also a label that is set to textvariable v which isn't relevant to the issue I am having, that is why it is that way in the dict.  That part seems to works fine.

Comment: @mScientist the two are completely different, actually. When you use self.appData["v"].get() you are accessing the value in the dict self.appData related to the "v" key, and then you try to use the get() method of whatever that value is (a string, in this case). Instead, self.appData.get("v") uses the get method of the dict self.appData to access the value related to the key "v", so you actually get the value.

Comment: Thank you @micric!!. You have been a great help!  I also have a question out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278846/class-destory-issue) that nobody has even commented on if you could take a look. :)